# how to get whole object as output when it is deeply nested in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, object, nested

```
 let common = {
        "id": 1364184,
        "url": "http:\/\/www.tvmaze.com\/episodes\/1364184\/the-big-bang- 
        theory-11x12-the-matrimonial-metric",
        "name": "The Matrimonial Metric",
        "season": 11,
                  "number": 12,
        "airdate": "2018-01-04",
        "airtime": "20:00",
        "airstamp": "2018-01-05T01:00:00+00:00",
        "runtime": 30,
        "image": {
          "medium": "sonie",
          "original": "agarwal" 
        },
        "summary": "<p>To discover who would be most qualified to be best 
         man and maid of honor at their wedding, Sheldon and Amy subject 
         their friends to a series of secret experiments. Also, Penny 
         reveals her true feelings about Amy.<\/p>",
        "_links": {
      "self": {
            "href": "http:\/\/api.tvmaze.com\/episodes\/1364184"
          }
        }
      }
 for (var x in common) {
 console.log(x+ "=" +common[x]);
if ( x === "image" ){
let z = common.image
 for (var y in z) {
  console.log( x + " = " + y+ " : " +z[y]);
 }
 }if ( x === "_links" ){
 let z = common._links.self
 for (var y in z) {
  console.log( x + " = " + y+ " : " +z[y]);
  }
 }
}
```

[output is posted in the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98iot.jpg)

i wrote maximum of the code for getting output but what i want is, get rid of some output which is boxed with black color which is shown in the figure.
so please help me with that...

Comment: `image` is not "deeply nested", it's a property of the object. Why can't you just use: `let z = common.image` without the loop? And what do you mean by "get rid of some output"? Do you want to delete some properties for the object?

Comment: so baiscally you want all the deep nested keys in the main objects right ?

Comment: How about ‘console.dir’?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take a recursive approach by keeping the visited keys for nested objects.

> Basically it takes an object and gets all key/value pairs from it.
>
> Then it iterate these key/value pairs by using a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) in a loop to get separate `key` and `value`.
>
> In the loop, `value` is checked for [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy)ness, because `null` is an object, but has no properties, because you need nested objects for a recursive call of `getKeyValues`.
>
> The type of `value` is taken and checked against `object`, then you have an object and take it a object and an array with all keys for the call of `getKeyValues`.
>
> If not create an output with all keys and the actual value.

```js
function getKeyValues(object, path = []) {
    Object
        .entries(object)
        .forEach(([key, value]) => {
            if (value && typeof value === 'object') {
                return getKeyValues(value, [... path, key])
            }
            console.log([... path, key].join('.'), value);
        });
}

var common = { id: 1364184, url: "http:\\/\\/www.tvmaze.com\\/episodes\\/1364184\\/the-big-bang-theory - 11 x12 - the - matrimonial - metric ", name: "The Matrimonial Metric", season: 11, number: 12, airdate: "2018-01-04", airtime: "20:00", airstamp: "2018-01-05T01:00:00+00:00", runtime: 30, image: { medium: "sonie", original: "agarwal" }, summary: "<p>To discover who would be most qualified to be best  man and maid of honor at their wedding, Sheldon and Amy subject their friends to a series of secret experiments.Also, Penny reveals her true feelings about Amy. <\\/p>", _links: { self: { href: "http:\\/\\/api.tvmaze.com\\/episodes\\/1364184" } } };    

getKeyValues(common);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: madam the answer is absoutely cool and its working too but i am unable to understand can you explain me..

Answer (score 1):

If you simply want to get the deeply nested object as a string, you can do the following:
`JSON.stringify(value)`

So for example:

```
var value = {
  one: {
    two: {
      three: [
        'one', 
        'two', 
        'three'
      ]
    }
  }
}
var asString = JSON.stringify(value);

console.log(asString)  # "{"one":{"two":{"three":["one","two","three"]}}}"
```

Answer (score 0):

That is happening because the following line is running every time without checks:

```
console.log(x+ "=" +common[x]);
```

You can instead have an if-else structure:

```
for (var x in common) {
  if (x === "image") {
    let z = common.image;
    for (var y in z) {
      console.log(x + " = " + y + " : " + z[y]);
    }
  } else if (x === "_links") {
    let z = common._links.self;
    for (var y in z) {
      console.log(x + " = " + y + " : " + z[y]);
    }
  } else {
    console.log(x + "=" + common[x]);
  }
}
```